# Matplotlib returning to begining of graph after switching data source

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

My program at initialization connects to coinbase server and loads some historic price values (usually the last 24h). The values are stored in a list called "cena". After that the graph is drawn for the first time
When that is done the program opens a web-socket connection on a ticker channel and appends any new prices to the "cena" list.
After every update the graph is being redrawn.

The problem occur when the first(and every next) update from the websocket comes and gets plotted. There is suddenly a line going back to the beginning an the graph is being drawn not from the part where the historical data ended but from the beginning [image](https://ibb.co/HGRXJmv)

I'm assuming (but i do not have any evidence to back up this theory) that the problem lays in the fact that i live in a different time zone than the server, and somewhere Im mixing up those time zones.

```
Code responsible for requesting historical data and ploting:
def Preignitor():
    end=(time.time()-3600)
    start=end-1800#86400
    for product_id in produkty:
        PR=Public_Requester()
        un_filtered=PR.Historic_rates_divider(start=start, end=end, skala=900, produkt=product_id)
        time.sleep(1)
        for v in range(len(un_filtered)):
            cena[produkty.index(product_id)].append(un_filtered[v][4])
            czas[produkty.index(product_id)].append(un_filtered[v][0])
def Preignitor_plot(produkty, cena, czas):
    fig=plt.figure()
    for x in range(len(produkty)):
        ax[x]=fig.add_subplot(len(produkty), 1 , 1+x)
        p[x], =ax[x].plot(czas[x], cena[x])
    plt.show(block=False)
def Plot_update(produkty, cena, czas):
    for x in range(len(produkty)):
        p[x].set_data(czas[x],cena[x])
        ax[x].relim()
        ax[x].autoscale_view()
    plt.pause(1e-3)

Code handling the ticker websocket updates:
while True:
    if q.not_empty:       # q is a queue, i use it to handle pasing data between threads    
        dane=q.get()        
        typ=dane.get('type',None)
        if typ=='ticker':
            price=dane.get('price', None)
            pair=dane.get('product_id',None)
            t=dane.get('time', None)            
            if t is not None:
                t=time.mktime(time.strptime(t, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
                b=True
    if b==True:
        alfa=time.time()
        b=False
        produkt_id=produkty.index(pair)
        cena[produkt_id].append(float(price))
        czas[produkt_id].append(t)
```

Comment: You are plotting a line. In matplotlib every data entry of the line is connected with a straight graph. The loopback to the beginning is due to the data wrapping around. You either need to set a break point for continuation, or use scatter points.

Comment: but If i use scatter plot the only change ill get is no lines, the new data will still get plotted at the front(left) instead of continuing (every new data point being plotted more and more to the right)

Comment: Wait so the wraparound is not intended?  You want the data to unwrap over 24 hours. In other words, the data you are getting is the unix time stamp, not binned in 0-24 hours? Edit: specifically what does `Historic_rates_divider` return?

Comment: at this point the x-axis is using epoch  i wanted to fix this first before adding/upgrading the displayed time in a readable form

Comment: Historic_rates_divider return a list of list [ time, low, high, open, close, volume ],:
 [[1415398768, 0.32, 4.2, 0.35, 4.2, 12.3 ],...] I take time for the x-axis and close for the y-axis

Comment: Right, is it possible to upload data that easily represents  a test case? I can probably help you  but the above code has too many unknowns for me to be sure what to point to. Additionally as you are using unix time stamps the timezone should be no issue; if you want to sanity check this, adjust the timezone in strptime.

Comment: Are You interested in some particular data? Or just a raw recording of what i get for the x,y axis. If You are interested the code is on [github](https://github.com/trewor007/trv2/blob/master/Aga_test_ploting_revamp.py)

Comment: The repo has no requirements.txt and I can't find some of the dependencies. It is easiest if you provide an [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)